# How do you programmatically get the current user's status?

Tags: 8, theming, users

I'm trying to get the currently logged-in user's status (active or blocked) in `template_preprocess_user`. I tried the following with no luck.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $user = $variables['user'];
  $variables['status'] = $user->status();
}

function MYTHEME_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $user = $variables['user'];
  $variables['status'] = $user->getStatus();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is Drupal 8, try [`$user->isBlocked()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AisBlocked).

If this is Drupal 7, you probably just need to call [`user_load($uid)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7.x) first in order to get a fully-loaded user object before checking the `$user->status`. Or try [`user_is_blocked($name)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_blocked/7.x).

Comment: Yes, Drupal 8, and  $user->isBlocked() worked!

For  $variables['status'] = $user->isBlocked() 

In my user twig file,  {{ status }} would display 1 for blocked user, and nothing for active user. 

So I was able to do  {% if status == '1' %} and do different things depending on if the user is active or blocked

Thanks very much!

Comment: If it worked, can you accept the answer? See stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers